# Why cart level discount not avaiable in api of bigcommerce?

Tags: php, api, e-commerce, bigcommerce

BigCommerce has this functionality on the dashboard under Marketing -> Cart-Level Discounts.

On this menu, I can create product discount, buy one get something else free.

[image: I need this]

I review the [v2](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/) and [v3](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/) endpoints of bigcommerce API, however, I can't find it anywhere.

I also found this category in [v2 api](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#marketing-reference) Coupon and Gift Certificates is available but Cart-Level Discounts is missing.

Is there an alternative way to do this via API? I just want to offer the customer if they add product X to their cart they will get this product Y for free.

Any Idea? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add a discount rule via API (this will affect all carts and customers) or provide a free product for a particular cart and customer?

Comment: I want to provide a free product for a particular cart and customer.

Comment: See V3 Cart API and find if you can achieve what you want

Comment: No is not. it cart for storefront creating, retrieving, updating etc

Comment: From the storefront API, you cannot restrict free product for a particular customer

Comment: There is a lot of stuff that's not available on their APIs and only God knows why. (Though I have theories, I don't want to rant) 
We were struggling to obtain "option set rules" and nope, not available. Sales data? No. Modifiers/Adjusters for non-SKU options? No. Optimized checkout API? Neh. 
So, even-though, "why" could be the correct question, it's not, when you're talking about BigCommerce. 
Thing is, what you are particularly asking is much more sophisticated, complex data against the primitive values we were looking, and yet nowhere to be found... I'd just do manually...